# Old system library units still present after upgrade to Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, upgrade, delphi-xe7

This is my first Delphi upgrade (from XE5 to XE7).  After the upgrade, my project still has open units (such as Vcl.Forms) that indicate the XE5 path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Rad Studio\12.0\Source\VCL\Common\Vcl.Forms.pas) when I hover the mouse over the name of the tab.  If I CTRL+click on the word "Forms" under "uses" on one of my units, the IDE directs me to this open page of Forms (12.0).  If I close the Forms page and again CTRL+click on "Forms", the IDE then opens a page that indicates it is the new path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Source\VCL\Common\Vcl.Forms.pas).  I close all these old pages, save and when I re-open, they are back.  I think maybe I need to update some library path or something, but when I go to Tools>Options>Delphi Options>Library everything either says 15.0 in the path or at least has a different path from the XE5 version.  Can anyone explain what is going on here and whether this is a problem?